# Getting the constant output in neural network

Tags: r, neural-network, backpropagation

I am using two excel file for training & testing purpose. Where I have D-Value corresponding to height in both the excel files.
Following is the code which I have written:

```
library(neuralnet)
library(readxl)

traininginput <- read_excel("Training_Data.xlsx")
net.D_value <- neuralnet(traininginput$D_value ~ traininginput$height,traininginput, hidden=3, threshold=0.01, rep = 100)


testdata <- read_excel("Test_data.xlsx")

net.test <- compute(net.D_value, testdata$height)

cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata$height,testdata$D_value,as.data.frame(net.test$net.result))

colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("height","Expected D_value","Neural Net D_value")

print(cleanoutput)
```

but I am getting the constant output for all the heights for the testing data as following:

```
     height Expected D_value Neural Net D_value
1    366.21        7.9599610        4.622364013
2    531.28        0.8100586        4.622364013
3   1005.37        2.7099610        4.622364013
4   1138.91        1.0595700        4.622364013
5   1199.37        0.7001953        4.622364013
6    966.48       13.3095700        4.622364013
7    398.41       32.5500500        4.622364013
8    674.71        1.3598630        4.622364013
9    662.16       20.3398400        4.622364013
10   841.57        2.0302730        4.622364013
11  1205.85        1.3603520        4.622364013
12  1289.47        7.0498050        4.622364013
13   954.32        0.6601563        4.622364013
14   396.73       14.0900900        4.622364013
15  1173.71        0.5400391        4.622364013
16   933.28        2.6503910        4.622364013
17  1658.32       14.6503900        4.622364013
18  1172.39       27.1201200        4.622364013
19   967.09        2.6298830        4.622364013
20   597.37        0.2797852        4.622364013
```

Can anyone please guide me that where I am going wrong and help me in writing the correct code?

Comment: Normalize your `traininginput`. Neural nets are very sensitive to the size of the numbers.

Comment: I am using this code: 
mean_theight <- mean(traininginput$height)
mean_tD_val <- mean(traininginput$D_value)
SD_theight <- sd(traininginput$height)
SD_tD_val <- sd(traininginput$D_value)
z_theight <- (traininginput$height-mean_theight)/SD_theight
z_tD_val <- (traininginput$D_value-mean_tD_val)/SD_tD_val
net.D_value <- neuralnet(z_tD_val ~ z_theight,cbind(z_theight,z_tD_val), hidden=3, threshold=0.01,rep=100)

Comment: testdata <- read_excel("Test_data.xlsx")
mean_vheight <- mean(testdata$height)
SD_vheight <- sd(testdata$height)
z_vheight <- (testdata$height-mean_vheight)/SD_vheight
net.test <- compute(net.D_value, z_vheight)
nn_D_val <- as.data.frame(net.test$net.result[,1])*SD_tD_val+mean_tD_val
cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata$height,testdata$D_value,nn_D_val)
colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("height","Expected D_value","Neural Net D_value")

Comment: you may want to do: train_data_rows<-nrow(train_data) dat <- rbind(training_data,test_data) scaled.dat <- scale(dat) train_data_norm <- scale.dat[1:train_data_rows,] test_data_norm <- scale.dat[train_data_rows:,]

Comment: problem solved?